# Function is returning wrong return

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with a function that returns wrong return instead of proper return.

Model:

```
export  module AbsModule {
    export class AbsModul{
        abs: string;
        state: boolean;
    }
  }
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { httpFactory } from '@angular/http/src/http_module';
import { AbsModule } from './abs-module';

@Injectable()
export class AbsService {
    private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAbs(): object {
           return  this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/abs/download").subscribe(data => {
               const returnFromFunction = this.assigneAbs(data);
               console.log(returnFromFunction);
               console.log(data);
               return returnFromFunction;

            })
    }

    private assigneAbs(data: object) {
        return Object.assign(new AbsModule.AbsModul(), data);
    }

}
```

Calling function:

```
@Component({})
export class TestClass  {
constructor(
    private tests: AbsService
) {}
test(): void {
    console.log(this.tests.getAbs())
}}
```

After that I am receiving return from subscribe instead of returnFromFunction. When I am calling this function first I see the return from Subscriber from the Test function, then I see the console log from returnFromFunction and data. Return returnFromFunction does not work - it does not return this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you just return the observable that's returned by the `http.get` method. You could fix this by awaiting for the response to come and then returning the resolved and processed value.

```
async getAbs(): Promise<object> {
    const response = await this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/abs/download").toPromise();
    return this.assigneAbs(response);
}
```

getAbs is an asynchronous method now so you will have to treat it appropriately in your test suite.

```
async test(): Promise<void> {
    console.log(await this.tests.getAbs());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Right Now I've received ZoneAwarePromise - I'll read about this - but in examples on network people was doing the same as me, moreover the examples on stackoverflow also has the solution as mine.
One more time - thanks.

Comment: The code you've put here is working fine, it's just asynchronous. It will assign data to AbsModul instance, but it will do so whenever observable you are creating with `http.get` produces data. So when you run the test suite without any awaiting, it finishes immediately and the callback passed to  `get` runs in the background when HTTP call returns some response, this is why you don't see the expected value returned in the test suite

Comment: Thanks - now I've understand. I've tried to received my abs from ZoneAwarePromise, and I've success by using then - but I don't success to assigned abs to member. I can take my variable only by using then - so I am wondering how I can prepare the function that will just be able to return the data received from rest. Is there any way?

Comment: yes, the function needs to be `async`, and if you want for the `Promise` to `resolve` before the code execution moves on,  you need to use `await`. Look at my example the method uses async before its name, and I use `await` to stop execution, and wait for the `http.get` returned `Promise` to resolve. I've added modified test method to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The http.get(...) method returns an observable, and the subscribe method returns an object of type [Subscription](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription).

Now, the argument being passed to the subscribe method is actually a callback, a function that returns void. Hence, having such callback return an actual value, 'returnFromFunction' in your case, is meaningless.

An observable serves as a publisher notifying its observers of some new data, so a better approach would be to have the service expose an observable and have the component (as well as a tester) subscribe to it:

```
export class AbsService {
    private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAbs(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/abs/download")
                        .map(data => this.assigneAbs(data));
    }

    private assigneAbs(data: object) {
        return Object.assign(new AbsModule.AbsModul(), data);
    }

}

export class TestClass {
    constructor(
        private tests: AbsService
    ) {}
    test(): void {
        this.tests.getAbs().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```